# Kotlin compiler error: expecting member declaration

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to *Android Studio* and *Java*. Trying to write a log in. Can someone help me understand what's going on with the code?

```
package com.example.XXX.myapplication

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android. widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_calendar.*

class Calendar : AppCompatActivity() {
    Button b1,b2; // Log in page** - b1 = log in; b2 - sign up;
    TextView tx1, tx2,tx3; // tx1 = username; tx2 = password;
    EditText ed1, ed2; // ed1 = username; ed2 = password inputs;

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar)

        // Example of a call to a native method
        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt1LogIn);
        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt2SignUp);
        ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
        ed2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        tx1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvUserName);
        tx2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPassword);
        tx3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvattempts);
}
```

Comment: Thats not the correct way to declare variables in Kotlin, Data type should be after the name of variable followed by 'colon'
e.g. `private var string : String = "my_string"`,

also no-need to put semi-colons at end of a single-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, in *Kotlin*, such a view declaration should be used with `lateinit var` in order to avoid the `expecting member declaration` error. E.g.:

```
private lateinit var b1: Button
private lateinit var b2: Button
private lateinit var tx1: TextView
etc...
```

But the most convenient part here is that when importing `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_calendar.*`, you do not have to instantiate views defined in `activity_calendar.xml` programmatically. Those views will be "instantiated for you". Just refer to the views by their names defined by `@+id/...`. E.g.:

```
etUserName.text = "Enter name"
```

Note that in *Kotlin* semicolons are optional and should not be used.

A starting point for further *Kotlin* learning: [Get Started with Kotlin on Android](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/get-started#kotlin)